# How to check multiple variables if has values?

Tags: php

How can i check if all has values do something if one is missing echo something with else. I try with isset but same, i miss something i think.

```
$da1="da1";
$ba2="";
$za3="za3";

if (!empty($da1)||!empty($ba2)||!empty($za3)) {
    echo $da1.$ba2.$za3;
}else{
    echo "one is missing";
}
```

My output is this :

```
da1za3
```

Comment: `!empty($da1)` is true, no other checks are done. you need to rethink your logic

Comment: You should be careful when using `empty()` and make sure that you know what it actually evaluates as empty. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USE && instead ||

```
if (!empty($da1)  && !empty($ba2)  && !empty($za3)) {
    echo $da1.$ba2.$za3;
}else{
    echo "one is mising";
}
```

Comment: isset only checks variable is set or not, it will not check its value (weather empty or not). Thanks

Comment: so what does exactly || ?

Comment: @AdrianKlark `Thank you, some answers are stupid here they don't read the question.` wont go down well, people are trying to help you. also `||` means `or` but hey we are all stupid!! If you took the time to read the manual you would know.

Comment: || checks weather one of condition is true, then it returns true. In your case, $da1 is not empty, so it will not throwing error.

Comment: @DhruvilPatel isset() does check if it is null as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No, it will not check.

Comment: @AdrianKlark - Since we don't know you consider to be a valid value, you get different answers. `null` is lack of a value. And empty string is actually something, an empty string. Sometimes you want an empty string to be valid, sometimes not. Before going off and calling answers "stupid", you might want to be _clear_ in your question.

Comment: @DhruvilPatel Read the manual: _"Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL."_: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: how to check which one is missing

Answer (score 2):

you can check with `isset` function

```
if(isset($da1,$da2,$da3))
    echo 'all ok';
```

Comment: Looks good, didn't know comma existed for this function